# publish to users wall using Facebook Application

Tags: facebook

I have a list of users id to users who have authorized my application
How can I  publish a post on their wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the top of my head, this is what you need to send POST Requests to with a valid access_token and parameters

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed
```